# Check if drive is connected in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need to know if a specific drive exists.

My application will install in two different drives, for example: drive F and G

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName=F:\Test\

[Dirs]
Name: G:\Test\storage;
```

If drive F does not exists Inno Setup show a message about it. But if drive G does not exist the installer stops working.

Comment: What is the question? What do you do after you find that the `G:` does not exist? Do you want to skip the creation of the `G:\Test\storage` directory? Or do you want to let use connect the drive and continue?

Comment: Martin, I need exactly warn to user connect the drive G before continue. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DirExists` function:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  while not DirExists('F:\') do
  begin
    MsgBox('Connect F:\ drive.', mbInformation, MB_OK); 
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```